# Spring validator handle error issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Estoy aplicando un desarrollo en donde estoy implementando Spring validations y estoy teniendo el problema que al momento en el que falla el insert de un objeto ( por un campo null ) , el try catch no me lo toma y me lanza una exception.

El objeto cuenta con esas 3 propiedades , en donde al momento de hacer el request , le estoy enviando el codigo en null para que falle y poder ver el mensaje correctamente.

```
@Column( name = "codigo" , unique = true , nullable = false , length = 255 )
@UniqueElements( message = "El codigo debe ser unico.")
@Length( max = 255 , message = "El codigo debe ser menos a 255 caracteres")
@NotNull( message = "El codigo es requerido.")
private String codigo;


@Column( name = "motivo" , unique = false , nullable = false , length = 255 )
@Length( max = 255 , message = "El motivo debe ser menos a 255 caracteres")
@NotNull( message = "El motivo es requerido.")
private String motivo;


@Column( name = "active" , unique = false , nullable = false )
@NotNull( message = "El estado es requerido.")
private Boolean active;
```

**Service**

Lo que espero es que al momento de hacer el add, obviamente el insert falle , pero pueda ser capturado por el catch().

```
@Transactional( rollbackFor = BusinessLayerException.class )
public String insertMotivoBaja( MotivoBajaTO motivoTO ) throws BusinessLayerException {

    try {
        
        MotivoBaja motivo = super.getPersistentObject( motivoTO , MotivoBajaTOT.class );
        return super.add( motivo );
        
    }catch (Exception e) {
        
        this.logger.error( e.getMessage() );
        
        if( e.getMessage().toLowerCase().startsWith("El".toLowerCase() ) ) {
            throw new BusinessLayerException(  e.getMessage());
        }
        
        throw new BusinessLayerException( "Error al dar de alta el motivo. Por Favor intente nuevamente." );    
    }
    
}
```

**Error**

> org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
>
> Caused by: javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'org.hibernate.validator.constraints.UniqueElements' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'codigo'

**Request ( body )**

```
{
  "codigo":null,
  "motivo":"No quiere ser mas cliente",
  "active": true 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException es una excepción de tipo runtime y tu catch tiene Exception que es el padre de los checked exception. Usa el catch con el runtimeexception que te aparece en tu log.